# jQuery Ajax Request - Response Text empty in Firefox

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery so hopefully this isn't too dumb of a question.  I'm creating a ajax request and it successfully completes but when I try and display the responseText it works in IE but is blank in Firefox.  I can't figure out why this would be.  I've removed the url but that is valid.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://*********.com/***/***',
                data: miSoap,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 30000,
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', '"'+soapAction+'"');
                },
                success:function(result, textStatus, xmlhttprequest){
                    alert(xmlhttprequest.responseText);
                    output = xmlhttprequest.responseText;
                },
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
            })
```

I just put in an function to catch if there was an error and it hit in firefox.  This is the response that I got.  Still don't understand.

```
Error: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.send]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js :: anonymous :: line 18"  data: no] 0 undefined
```

Comment: Are you testing from the same domain that included in your jQuery call? Because [https://yourdomain.com](https://yourdomain.com) is not [https://www.yourdomain.com](https://www.yourdomain.com) in this case

Comment: @ZoltanToth No they are of different domains which is the reason that I'm using jQuery in place of traditional httpRequest objects because I read that you can move cross domains with jQuery.  Am I correct in this?  And if that isn't true why does it work in IE but not Firefox?

Comment: you can't do cross-domain scripting with plain jQuery. Take a look at http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide as a possible solution

Comment: @ZoltanToth Okay so I don't have access to the server I'm requesting data from but I can setup a php proxy on one of my servers that can make the request to the other domain with the data I need.  The thing is that I need to set things like I did about with the requestHeader and async values as well as sending my request.  You don't know of a php proxy that allows me to set this up do you?  Or an example online where they show the javascript setup.  I've been looking but can't find one.  Thanks.